# SQL GroupBy to get count of column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `Rates` having data as follows:

```
Code  Value
 A     FC
 B     PC
 A     PC
 A     FC
 B     FC
 C     PC
```

I am expecting output as follows:

```
Code  FC  PC
 A    2    1
 B    1    1
 C    0    1
```

I have written query as follows:

```
SELECT
  Rates.Code AS Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Rates.Value='FC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FC,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Rates.Value='PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC
FROM
 Rates
GROUP BY Rates.Code
ORDER BY Rates.Code
```

It's not giving the output in expected format, I guess I need to use Pivot but not sure how to write it as I am new to SQL.
I have written python code as follows which is working fine for me, It will be very helpful if anyone know how to write SQL for the same.

```
Rates.groupby(['Code'])['Value'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)`
```

Comment: What's the output it's giving you?

Comment: your query works in my test. What are you getting?

Comment: @Rajat I am getting only 1 and 0 values for FC and PC.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare Could it be some hidden special characters in the value field? Try using like '%FC%' in the case expression to see if that's the issue.

Comment: @Rajat , In that case do I need to use `like` instead of `=`.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare Yeah so change `Rates.Value='FC'` to `Rates.Value like '%FC%'` and same for PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks OK to me, but you may have problems if you have NULL values in the "Value" column. In that case you can wrap the column with "coalesce", like this:

```
SELECT
  Rates.Code AS Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(Value, '')='FC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FC,
  SUM(CASE WHEN coalesce(Value, '')='PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC
FROM
 Rates
GROUP BY Rates.Code
ORDER BY Rates.Code
```

Well, that's assuming that's your issue. It would help if you add the expected output and the output you are getting in your question.

Comment: No I don't have NULL values as I am already filtering data on the basis of FC and PC, Is additional  columns can create issue? AS this table contains 10 more column also.